# java запись строки в реестр Windows

Tags: java, windows, реестр, запись

Подскажите пожалуйста простейший пример записи строки, например "ABCD" в реестр Windows и потом, соответственно чтение стоки из реестра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант - можно использовать `WinRegistryWrapper` из `com.sun.deploy.association.utility.WinRegistryWrapper;`

Там, скорее всего, найдете все или почти все необходимые вам методы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из фото выше, можно добавлять/устанавливать/удалять ключи/значения в реестр/из реестра.

Как пример:

```
WinRegistryWrapper.WinRegSetValueEx(WinRegistryWrapper.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Prefs", "test" , "myValue");
```

Устанавливаем ключ с именем `test` со значением `myValue` в главной ветке с именем `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` по пути `SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Prefs`

еще:

```
String value = WinRegistryWrapper.WinRegQueryValueEx(WinRegistryWrapper.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Prefs\\jetbrains", "user_id_on_machine");
System.out.printf(value);
```

выведет значение ключа `user_id_on_machine`, который лежит в главной ветке с название `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, в поддиректории `SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Prefs\\jetbrains`

другой пример:

```
String keyNames[] = WinRegistryWrapper.WinRegGetValues(WinRegistryWrapper.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\Common", 100);
for (int i = 0; i < keyNames.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(keyNames[i]);
}
```

Выведет все имена ключей в главной ветке с именем `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` в поддиректории `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\Common`

Comment: Не работает: 
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/deploy/association/utility/WinRegistryWrapper

Comment: @arachnoden оно вполне себе работает и корректно отрабатывает. Ваша ошибка никак не связана с корректной отработкой данного пакета.....Эта ошибка вылетает когда виртуальная машина Java во время исполнения кода не может найти определённый класс, который был доступен во время компиляции. Может вы `deploy.jar` не добавили (что скорее всего) или  classpath другой. Рекомендую почитать информацию о данной ошибке (она слишком обширна чтоб уместить в комментарий описание и пути решения) и решить её..... а коды, приведенные выше - работают.

Comment: @arachnoden тестирование было на Java 1.8, к слову............и  банальный пастбин консольного приложения вам pastebin.com/rK9HgguJ для понимания

Answer (score 0):

Нашел еще такой вариант, но к сожалению он делает запись в реестре только в подкаталогах Java

```
Preferences prefs;
String key;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("/branch/leaf");
    prefs.put("key", "ABCD");
    key = prefs.get("key", "noKey");
    System.out.println("key - "+key);
}
```